# template should match all elements "b" which have at least one ancestor "a"

Tags: xslt, xpath

```
<xsl:template match="//a//b">...</xsl:template>
```

does almost what I want. but it does not select for example this one: (b's inside b's inside a's)

```
<x>
   <y>
      <a>
         <b>
            <b>THIS</b>
         </b>
      </a>
   </y>
</x>
```

someone an idea?

I tried this, what does the same:

```
<xsl:template match="//b[ancestor::a]">
```

Comment: Show us the complete code. How are you sure that this template is being called, at all.

Comment: A `template` on its own does not "select" anything.  _If_ there is anything in your stylesheet that would cause templates to be applied to the nested `b` element _then_ that template would match it, but we can't tell from this tiny snippet whether or not that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it does not select for example this one: (b's inside b's inside a's)

First, *match* does not *select*, it matches. As such, the `//` prefix doesn't do anything for a *match* pattern. In any case, all of these match patterns:

```
match="//a//b"
match="a//b"
match="//b[ancestor::a]">
match="b[ancestor::a]">
```

will match **both** `b` elements in your example. If you're finding something else, check your method: most likely, your template does not apply any templates - so the processor never gets to the inner `b`.